# How to design thread safe class when separating business logic from POCOs

Tags: c#, multithreading, controller, poco

I like to separate business logic out of POCOs into controllers.

If an object must be thread safe, where do I put the lock code? In the POCO itself? Or in a controller?

Might make sense because value types cannot be locked?

I.e., the controller:

```
namespace Project1.Controllers
{
    public class LogManagerController
    {
        private object _lock = new object();

        public LogManager Fill(TimeSpan interval, DateTime? lastLog)
        {
            return new LogManager {Interval = interval, LastLog = lastLog};
        }

        public void Update(LogManager logManager, DateTime lastLog)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                logManager.LastLog = lastLog;
            }
        }

        public DateTime? Get(LogManager logManager)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return logManager.LastLog;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The model:

```
namespace Project2.Models
{
    public class LogManager
    {
        public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put business logic into controller, what will you do if your business logic is needed by a non web based application? I am assuming you are talking about controllers in a web MVC framework.

Comment: If LogManager has an actual need to be thread-safe, then it's probably not really a POCO. Offloading the thread-safety to another class is risky, because any future use case where another component of your application needs a LogManager will either require the programmer to remember to use LogManagerController, or they'll end up re-implementing the locking.

Comment: Hmm, then I wonder if this class should be places in a models namespace or elsewhere @RuslanD

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see where you might run into thread safety here is due to `Interval` and `LastLog` needing to be kept in sync. If that's the case, then avoid the problem altogether by making that class immutable:

```
namespace Project2.Models
{
    public class LogManager
    {
        public LogManager(TimeSpan interval, DateTime? lastLog)
            => (Interval, LastLog) = (interval, lastLog);

        public TimeSpan Interval { get; }
        public DateTime? LastLog { get; }
    }
}
```

Then, when the values change, create a new instance of `LogManager`, rather than mutating an existing value.

But having said that, there's nothing abut your code that suggests this is the case. You update `LastLog` but leave `Interval` alone. So it's unclear why you feel this class might not be thread safe already.

Comment: I am more concerned as to where in my application I should put the locking code. In the POCO or in a controller?

Comment: @Hoppe as your question stands, it’s unclear why you are considering locking it the first place.